# Ionic is throwing error after uploading build file to Firebase host

Tags: angularjs, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, build

i am trying to upload ionic web app on browser. i used `ionic build browser --prod --release` the code successfully build.
then i deployed app using `firebase deploy`
the app also successfully uploaded. now when i try to login it shows error in browser console

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:50)
    at eval (C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/src_lazy:44)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:4354)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:4345)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:50)
    at eval (C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/src_lazy:44)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:4354)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:4345)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller-base.js:327)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller-base.js:315)
    at eval (C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller-base.js:370)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:4354)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
defaultErrorLogger @ C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:1289
ErrorHandler.handleError @ C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:1349
IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/ionic-angular/util/ionic-error-handler.js:65
next @ C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:4983
schedulerFn @ C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:4056
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:238
SafeSubscriber.next @ C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:185
Subscriber._next @ C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:4042
NgZone.triggerError @ C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:4414
onHandleError @ C:/Users/allud/Code/webApp/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js:4375
t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3
r.runGuarded @ polyfills.js:3
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3
n.microtaskDrainDone @ polyfills.js:3
o @ polyfills.js:3
Promise resolved (async)
r @ polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleMicroTask @ polyfills.js:3
f @ polyfills.js:3
c @ polyfills.js:3
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3
webpackJsonpCallback @ main.js:22
(anonymous) @ 1.main.js:1
```

can someone please tell what the problem is?

you can check the link here on https://restroapp-40ae7.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: i am deploying web app for 1st time. as far as i know i guess there is some problem with my imports as it is showing my home directory addresses. is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

updated CLI with latest version and then again built the app. now working fine.